# Почему ejs отображает данные в одну строку

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

Существует шаблон ejs, который выводит данные из mongo, проблема в том, что он выводит массив в одну строку, хотя я использую список li

route

```
router.get('/', auth, async (req, res) => {
try {
    const datauser = await User.find({username: req.user.username})
    res.render('result', { User:datauser, title: 'Посещенные страницы'})
    }  catch(err) {
      console.log(err.message);
   }
})
```

ejs

```
<div class="results">
        <h1 class="resul"><%=title%></h1>
        
        <ul class="litem">
            <% User.forEach(function (User, i) { %>
         <li>
            <%= User.resultat%>   
        </li>
         <% }) %>
        </ul>      
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
результат отображается в одной строке, а тег </ brприводит к ошибке

**заранее спасибо**

Comment: Может `li` в данном случае строчные у вас. Добавьте им `style="display:block"` для проверки

Comment: Добавлял, все равно выводит в строку, проблема в том что если я создам массив просто кодом js где нибудь в роуте скажем, то он выводиться списком, а из mongo  почему то в строку.

Comment: Можете показать в коде элемента, какая страница в итоге получается?

Comment: @OliverPatterson Не знаю как  правильно сюда скинуть скрин, но в общем просто выводятся данные  массива через запятую в одну строку вместо списка li

Comment: Просто ctrl+v в ваш пост.

Comment: @OliverPatterson добавил

Comment: Код элемента..)

Comment: @OliverPatterson так код есть в вопросе ejs это кусок кода который отвечает за список.

Comment: Из DevTools, чтобы было видно, какой html получился в итоге.

Comment: Вангую что у вас один элемент User возвращается из монги. А массив в поле User.resultat

Comment: @AlexeyTen  а массив в колекции оно не перебирает?

Comment: С чего бы? Вы же этого не написали в коде

Comment: @Alexey Ten  а что я пропустил, как можно дописать чтобы выводило  нормально?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте для div использовать:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

или тэг `<br>` а не `</br>`